# AwesomeFont to expand equally from the center on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an edit button, that i want to increase in size when the user hovers over it. It does however stay in line with the text, and doesnt expand equally on every side of the icon, it only expands in the right upper corner.

```
#quiznavn::after {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f044";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: black;
}
#quiznavn:hover::after {
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f044";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kbw1yurh/

Comment: Can you please share a link of your code from jsfiddle. At least your question will get clear to me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kbw1yurh/

Comment: So you want the button to expand equally? is this what your question is all about .. right.

Comment: Exactly what i want to achieve :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
transform:scale(1.5)
```

instead with transform-origin set to 50% 50%.

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/c17fjsx8/

note: if you're using this on iOS you made need to prefix this with -webkit-transform, -webkit-transform-origin, etc or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this button you're referring to in your code, so I'll assume you have one.

```css
.btn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12pt;
  display: table;
}

.btn span {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70px;
}

.btn span:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 30px;
}

.btn:hover i {
  font-size: 17pt;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="btn">
  <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><span>Click me!</span>
</button>
```

Comment: No this is not the proper answer. But still your approach is good I appreciate.

Comment: It's a valid answer, but I agree that @foreyez solution is better. Good luck!